# "relative to" vs "divided by"

Tags: expressions

Regarding "x = A/B" like the following examples, which is "x equals A divided by B," is it correct to say "x is A relative to B" (e.g., "winners relative to total applicants") when I want to express in everyday language instead of mathematical terms?

In other words, can "divided by" and "relative to" be used interchangeably? If not, what would be more appropriate ways to say these expressions?

- x = A/B
- x = winners/total applicants
- x = adult population/total population
- x = expenses/total earnings

These expressions (without "x =") are in the subject line of a table (with calculated numbers) and I would like to explain them in writing using non-mathematical language.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You could sometimes use "relative to" to replace "divided by," but not always.  I don't think this question can be answered without more context.  We need full sentences for those examples, or some indication of how you would want to use the mathematical equation in a non-mathematical context.

Comment: Thank you, Juhasz, for your comment. I added a sentence. Does this help you understand the context?

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways you can explain this without using ‘divided by’, and I am not sure ‘relative to’ is particularly good for these cases. I would recommend:

**as a [proportion](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/proportion) of**

as it is quite consistent with being equivalent to a decimal value (0.3, 0.9 etc.), whereas *relative to* seems to me less so (it suggests more a ratio).

e.g

> This shows winners *as a proportion of* total applicants.
>
> This shows adults *as a proportion of* the total population.
>
> This shows expenses *as a proportion of* total earnings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, David. Though this makes sense, I think numbers in my cases are actually ratios. Can I say "the ratio of winners to total applicants"?

Comment: If the values are ratios in the form ‘1:3’ (instead of the number 0.33), you can certainly say, “this shows the ratio of winners to total applicants”.

Comment: Thank you again for responding! Those are actually decimal values as the result of calculation. According to American Heritage, "A ratio can often also be expressed as a decimal or percentage," so I'm a bit confused...

Comment: I wouldn’t use ‘ratio’ for decimal values, whatever the American Heritage dictionary says. Usage in my area of science would always suggest x:y, rather than x/y.